# View sizing with setting navigationbar to hidden with push/pop 

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

So before I push a new viewController onto the stack in a certain view, I set the navigationBar to hidden I notice that it disappears before the next screen gets pushed and the slide animation happens (because I need a UIToolbar at the top).

So question #1: is there a way to push a new view controller and setting the navigationbar to hidden, and not getting the hide animation until after the new view controller is on screen.  it looks funny that the navigation bar hides then pushes the new view controller.

Once the new view controller is present, when I pop it off, I set the navigation bar back

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar  setHidden:NO];
```

But when it is popped, the navigationbar is not back any more.  Is it because this navigationBar is for the current navigationController and not the new one that is being presented after the pop? (question #2)

Question 3: Realizing it isn't showing my navigationBar, in the viewController that gets presented after the pop, in its viewDidAppear, I added

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
}
```

which shows the navigationBar, but the view size is incorrect since it seems like once the navigation bar was hidden, the rest of the view took up the empty space, and then the navigationBar is on top of the content.  Is there anything I can do about this?  Or am I approaching it incorrectly with push and pop?(question #3).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting issue.  You could try changing the `hidden` property in `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear`, but it seems like that might not give the desired results either.

Can you present the view controller modally instead of making the navigation bar disappear?  If it's the last view controller on the stack, that would be possible.  It might also make more sense to the user to see a view controller presented differently.  This might indicate to the user that navigating away from this view controller is no longer done with the Back Button.  It could be more reasonable than having the navigation bar just disappear.

If you still wanted the view controller to slide in from the right, I don't think it can be done with a modal view controller.  But, you could do that by animating a view that fills the screen.  (You just add the view with a frame that has origin.x equal to the width of the screen.  Then, in the animation, you change origin.x to 0.0.  Let me know if you need more detail on this.)

However, I would recommend presenting the view controller in a different manner from the way a view is generally presented by a navigation controller.  Because, essentially, you are no longer letting the user navigate away from this view as he/she generally would from within a navigation controller.  (So, my response to question #3 would be 'yes'.)

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the very same problem (only in reverse: I was starting from a NavigationBar being hidden and pushing a view where I wanted the NavigationBar visible), and there's actually an extremely easy fix.

Simply replace your calls:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
```

with

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

In my code, I call these statements in the `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` methods of each respective View Controller.

I just tried this solution in the order you are using (visible, then hidden), and it seems to work just as well.